# How to show scroll bar always on iOS 15 with out user touching the screen?

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, scrollbar

We have a Web Application where we show scroll bar for user to scroll.

That scroll bar is working fine in Desktop Browsers and Android Browsers but not in Apple Devices iOS 15 (Safari Browser)

Current Behaviour :

Scroll bar is showing up on when user touch the screen and scrolls UP/DOWN in Apple Safari Browser, which is iOS default Behaviour.

Expected Behaviour:

Scroll bar should be shown by default with out any user interactions.

I have tried below code . It works iOS 14 below device (safari) but not in iOS 15

```css
.frame {
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 3em;
    width: 10em;
    line-height: 1em;
}
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 2px;
}
.frame::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 11px;
}

.frame::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white; /* should match background, can't be transparent */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="frame">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you found any solution here ?

Comment: it seems that in safari 14.5 they dropped support for scrollbar styling, I have not found the solution for permanent scroll bar on safari 15 https://www.lambdatest.com/web-technologies/css-scrollbar-support-on-safari-15

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

“Creating Custom Scrollbars for Your Website as a Web Component: A Workaround for iOS Safari Limitations with Jest Tests”

https://medium.com/@craigmroberts/creating-custom-scrollbars-for-your-website-as-a-web-component-a-workaround-for-ios-safari-c5f6def5b408